# How to post back to same page without a form using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Hi I would like to know how to first post to a current page using the following code:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_GET['button']) === true){
        echo 'Albums';
    }   
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Albums">
</form>
```

I can't seem to get the button when clicked to echo out Albums on current page??  But my main question was how can I achieve what I am trying to do without using a form just a link or button that can return an action using PHP? Is this possible with PHP alone? If not then how can I use whatever scripting is needed to return the PHP function?

Comment: Your method is POST, but you're checking if a GET variable exists...?

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?button=1">button</a>`

Comment: You should use <input type="submit" in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You submit the data as post, so you have to check for POST.

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST['button'])){
        echo 'Albums';
    }   
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Albums" />
</form>
```

Additionally I would either use `<input type="submit"` or `<button type="submit" name="button">Albums</button>`.

Comment: OH wow I can't believe how simple that was.  But now can I do this without a form because when I refresh that Confrim Form Resubmission window pops up how can I get rid of that when I refresh the page?

Comment: well, you could do a redirect after you processed the posted data. 

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    /* do something */
    header('Location: /your/page/');
    exit; 
}  
you have to ensure that the php part is at the very beginning of your file, otherwise the header redirect would not work because headers were already sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the action attribute, the form will post back to your current script.

If you want that `$_GET` variable to have any of your form fields, set your form's method to `GET`, or don't set it at all.  (It defauls to `GET`).

Comment: Is GET really always the default?

Comment: @Jocelyn, In any context I've ever seen it, yes.  Not sure if it's in the spec or not.